# C# prevent same combobox column in datagridview from being autogenerated

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

In my winForm application I'm adding combobox column in datagridview using the following code:

```
dgvLoadTable.DataSource = null;
crudLoadData(0); //Calls function to load data in datagridview and recordNum is 
                 //set to 0 for showing the header only in dgvLoadTable
dgvLoadTable.ReadOnly = false;
dgvLoadTable.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboIsNew = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
int i= dgvLoadTable.Columns["ColumnName"].Index;
dgvLoadTable.Columns.Insert(i, dgvCol);
dgvLoadTable.Columns[i].HeaderText = dgvLoadTable.Columns[i + 1].HeaderText;
dgvLoadTable.Columns[i + 1].Visible = false;
```

This code is executed under treeView_NodeMouseClick event.Now it works fine the first time I click on the node. But from second time it keeps adding the previously added column at the first column index of the datagridview. Because, I'm rebinding all columns except for the cboIsNew (that already been added to the grid), so it now became first and other columns from dataGridView source are re-added at the end.

How can I overcome this problem? I tried checking if the column already exists but couldn't solve it.FYI, my data source is entity model.

Comment: I see taht you are setting the DataSource = null but where are you Binding the DataGridview...? show all relevant code please

Comment: I'm doing that to remove previously loaded data from datagridview

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy. Before loading data to datagridview just write the following line:

```
dataGridViewName.Columns.Clear();
```

In this case:

```
dgvLoadTable.Columns.Clear();
```